# Energy distribution of photon from neutral pion ($\pi^0$) decay

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, pions

The laboratory-frame energy $E_\gamma$ of either photon is uniformly distributed between $E_{min} = \frac{1}{2}E_{\pi}(1-\beta)$ and $E_{max} = \frac{1}{2}E_{\pi}(1+\beta)$, where $E_\pi$ is the energy of the pion and $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$ is the pion's velocity divided by the velocity of light.

I read this paragraph on **Statistical data analysis by Glen Cowan in pg.31** and tried to study why. And below is what I've thought.

In CM frame, pi0 decays to two photons isotropically and each photon has energy of $\frac{1}{2}E_{\pi}$. But in the lab frame, pi0 is boosted in a certain direction with kinetic energy $(\gamma-1)E_{\pi}$
We can approximate this as...
\begin{align}
\ \gamma-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\simeq1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}-1=\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}
\end{align}
with an assumption that v is smaller than c.
Then the photon can have its maximal energy of $\frac{1}{2}E_\pi(1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}$) (if photon's direction is aligned with pi0's direction)
and its minimal energy of $\frac{1}{2}E_\pi(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})$(if photon's direction is anti-aligned with pi0's direction).
Since two photon decay isotropically in CM frame, energy distribution of photon from neutral pion decay shows uniform distribution between [$\frac{1}{2}E_\pi(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})$,$\frac{1}{2}E_\pi(1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}$)].

But here, I got $β^2$ not just β. Is there anything wrong with my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your Lorentz transformation. In the CM frame, each photon has energy:
$$E_\gamma^{CM}=\frac{m_\pi}{2}$$
with $m_\pi$ the rest mass of the pion. It is related to its energy in the lab frame by:
$$E_\pi=\gamma m_\pi$$
Back to the lab frame, each photon goin in direction $\theta,\phi$ (spherical coordinates with respect to the lab’s velocity) in the CM frame has energy:
$$
E_\gamma^L=E_\gamma^{CM}(\gamma-\beta\cos\theta)
$$
which you can rewrite:
$$
E_\gamma^L=\frac{1}{2}(E_\pi-m_\pi\beta\cos\theta)
$$
You recover the extremal values at:
$$
E_\pm=\frac{1}{2}(E_\pi\pm m_\pi\beta)
$$
and the distribution is uniform, since if the photons scatter isotropically in the CM frame, $\cos\theta$ is distributed uniformly.

In the non relativistic limit, $\beta\ll 1$ so $E_\pi=m_\pi$ and you recover Cowan’s claim.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Now I got this :D